# How to extract values of all fields with same name and add them as a list to the value attribute of output field in XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt, xml-parsing, xslt-1.0

I have an xml file where there are some fields with same name but different values:

```
<field1>value1</field1>
<field1>value2</field1>
```

I want to extract value1 and value2 and add it to the value attribute of the output field as a list of strings:

```
<field value="['value1', 'value2']">...</field>
```

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: Are you sure you want to do this? It's very easy to push multiple needles into a single haystack - it's not so easy to pull them out later.

Comment: @michael.hor257k yes...that is how i want to transform the xml.

Comment: If [that](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23974607/3016153) is the correct answer, then this question is even more poorly worded than I thought.

Comment: sorry...english not my native language.

Comment: This has nothing to do with your English. Why do you use *field1* as an example, if there is no *field2* or *field3*? Why didn't you tell us that you want to extract the values in all fields with a **specific** (known) name - and not (as your title says) "all fields with **same** name"? (Those are rhetorical question, no need to answer.) This would have been avoided if you had posted a **complete** example of the input (including the entire tree), and your attempted XSLT.

Answer (score 1):

This is a [grouping problem](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.xml), you seem to want to group elements by their name or `local-name()`:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
        xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:key name="name" match="fields/*" use="local-name()"/>

<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="fields/*[generate-id() = generate-id(key('name', local-name())[1])]">
  <field>
    <xsl:attribute name="value">
      <xsl:text>[</xsl:text>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="key('name', local-name())" mode="list"/>
      <xsl:text>]</xsl:text>
    </xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:text>...</xsl:text>
  </field>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="fields/*[not(generate-id() = generate-id(key('name', local-name())[1]))]"/>

<xsl:template match="fields/*" mode="list">
  <xsl:if test="position() > 1">
    <xsl:text>, </xsl:text>
  </xsl:if>
  <xsl:text>'</xsl:text>
  <xsl:value-of select="."/>
  <xsl:text>'</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

That way the input

```
<fields>
<field1>value1</field1>
<field1>value2</field1>
<field2>value3</field2>
<field3>value4</field3>
<field2>value5</field2>
</fields>
```

is transformed into the result

```
<fields>
   <field value="['value1', 'value2']">...</field>
   <field value="['value3', 'value5']">...</field>
   <field value="['value4']">...</field>
</fields>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you actually have a well-formed XML with a root element:

```
<fields>
    <field1>value1</field1>
    <field2>value2</field2>
</fields>
```

With this stylesheet you will obtain the result you want:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="fields">
        <field>
            <xsl:attribute name="value">
                <xsl:text>[</xsl:text>
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
                <xsl:text>]</xsl:text>
            </xsl:attribute>
        </field>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="fields/*">
        <xsl:text>'</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        <xsl:text>'</xsl:text>
        <xsl:if test="position() != last()">
            <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I'm not considering the *contents* of your `field` elements. The result of this transformation is

```
<field value="['value1','value2']"/>
```

Comment: It seems you've misplaced the closing apostrophe: it should come before the `<xsl:if>`.

Comment: @helderdarocha did u mean `field1` when u wrote `fields` ?

Comment: No. I'm referring to a *root* node. Since you didn't provide one in your example, I added one and called it `fields`. It represents the *parent* of your `field1` and `field2` nodes.

Comment: @coder006 But it seems I interpreted your question incorrectly. You actually have *two* `field1` elements and not `field1` and `field2`. In that case it's a grouping problem as observed in the answer by @MartinHonnen.

Comment: @helderdarocha exactly...there are two or more `field1` elements